# Show custom post type endpoint in REST API just if user has capability

Tags: custom-post-types, user-access, rest-api

I created a custom post type for WP, that should just be visitable for user that have a custom capability `read_cpt`. Within templates and `pre_get_posts` I can run checks to include or exclude the CPT by using `current_user_can()`.

I don't want the CPT, not even the endpoint, to show up within the REST API, to keep it top secret, as long as a user doesn't have the custom capability.

The only way I could figure out to hide the endpoints in the API to run this code.

Register post type for "classic" WP:

```
function add_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        [...]
        'public'                => false,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => false,
        'show_in_rest'          => false,
    );
    register_post_type( 'cpt', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_post_type', 0 );
```

and separately add it to the REST API:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_rest_support', 25 );
function cpt_rest_support() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    if ( current_user_can( 'read_addresses' ) ) {
        //be sure to set this to the name of your post type!
        $post_type_name = 'address';
        if( isset( $wp_post_types[ 'cpt' ] ) ) {
            $wp_post_types[ 'cpt' ]->show_in_rest = true;
        }
    }
}
```

By creating a custom `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` class I couldn't find a way to hide the endpoint by modifying any of the `*_permissions_check`

Is there something like a "show_in_rest_permition_check" argument for  `register_post_type()` or is the described way the only method?

Answer (score 2):

The REST API has no parameters, options to solve this - in my opinion. But you should register only if the users have the capability in his role, like the follow example.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {

    // Exit, if the logged in user have not enough rights.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Register Meta Data.
    register_meta( 'post', 'foo', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    ));
});
```

That's fire the custom data in the REST API only, if the user have enough rights, capabilities in his role. My `register_meta()` is only an example, that should also work with your additional parameter for `register_post_type`, like `$wp_post_types[ 'cpt' ]->show_in_rest = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely solely on hiding it.

Instead, return an error in the handler:

```php
if (!current_user_can('read_addresses')) {
    return new WP_REST_Response('restricted', 403);
}
```

To hide it as well, filter the content of the hooks `rest_index` and `rest_namespace_index`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [register_rest_route()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) function.

```
if( current_user_can( 'read_addresses' ) ) {
    register_rest_route( 'namespace/v1', 'cpt', array(
        'methods' => array( 'GET' ),
        'callback' => 'callback_function',
        'permission_callback' => 'permission_callback_function'
    ) );
}
```

Your `callback_function` would handle the request and return the response. The `permissions_callback_function` would check the user permissions and return an error if the user does not have the specified capabilities. In this case the permissions callback is probably not necessary, but it wouldn't hurt to have it in place just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this worked for me following @Drivingralle requirements. You could use `current_user_can()` as a boolean switch to modify `show_in_rest` parameter behaviour:

```
function add_post_type() {

    $show_in_rest = current_user_can( 'read_cpt' ); //this will return true or false

    $args = array(
        [...]
        'public'                => false,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => false,
        'show_in_rest'          => $show_in_rest, //bool switch from current_user_can()
    );
    register_post_type( 'cpt', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_post_type' );
```

This way the custom post type is only shown in rest for users with the required capability.